# How do I read conf.py setting in Sphinx extension node?

Tags: python, configuration-files, python-sphinx

```
from docutils.parsers.rst.directives.images import Figure
class MyFigure(Figure):
    def run(self):
        # here I need to read the 'thumbnails_folder' setting
        pass

def setup(app):
    app.add_config_value('thumbnails_folder', '_thumbnails', 'env')
```

How can I access the config value in `.run()`? I read [sources](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib/src) of Sphinx-contrib, but did not see things done in my way, so they accessed `conf.py` the way I can't. Or should I do it in a different manner?

All I want to do is translate this

```
.. figure:: image/image.jpg
```

into this:

```
.. image:: image/thumbnails/image.jpg
   :target: image/image.jpg
```

[Here's the extension code](http://pastebin.com/pMhKnTkv)

(the thumbnail is generated with PIL). And also put the `:target:` into downloadable files (As I see, only builder instances can do this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [build environment](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/envapi.html) holds a reference to the Config object. Configuration variables can be retrieved from this object:

```
def run(self):
    env = self.state.document.settings.env  # sphinx.environment.BuildEnvironment 
    config = env.config                     # sphinx.config.Config
    folder = config["thumbnails_folder"] 
    ...
```